# Distributed TensorFlow | VGG 16

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to develop a VGG 16 model distributed over a single server.

I have one available GPU server with 1 CPU and two GPU cards. I have the code to treat them as different servers and implement distributed tensorflow over this.

But the major problem which I see in my code is that the run-time is very, very bad- its currently at 20 minutes for a single epoch vs 180 seconds on a single GPU.

I am assuming that there is something wrong in my code as the distributed tensorflow is taking 20 minutes and the single GPU version is taking 180 seconds as well.

Could someone tell me what kind of bottle-neck I am creating?

Below is the code for distributed TensorFlow. I'd like to first have this sorted.

Also my hardware and software configurations:

- TensorFlow 1.2
- CUDA 7.5
- cuDNN 5.1

I have one utility and one main code.

#### conv_utils.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
from numpy import genfromtxt
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

from PIL import Image, ImageOps

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.preprocessing as skp
import sklearn

import time
import csv
import random

path = "***"

def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

def return_config():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    config.log_device_placement = False
    #config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
    return config

cpu = ':/cpu:0'
gpu1 = ':/gpu:0'
gpu2 = ':/gpu:0'

def parameters(var_name, shape, var_type):
    var = tf.placeholder(dtype=var_type, shape=shape, name=var_name)
    return var  

def weights(var_name, shape, var_type):
    var = tf.get_variable(name=var_name,shape=shape,dtype=var_type,initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=0))
    return var

def import_images(name):
    img = Image.open(name)
    img = np.asarray(img)
    return img

def one_hot_encoding(data):
    a = tf.one_hot(data,len(np.unique(data)))
    with tf.Session(config=return_config()) as sess:
        b = sess.run(a)
    return b

def label_import_oh(file_name):
    input_labels = np.genfromtxt(path + file_name, dtype='U', skip_header=1, delimiter=',')
    input_label_op = input_labels[:,1]
    le = skp.LabelEncoder()
    input_label_le = le.fit_transform(input_label_op)

    input_label_oh = one_hot_encoding(input_label_le)
    return input_labels, input_label_oh

def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]
    print("Out of mini batches")

def conv(inp, weight, stride, conv_type):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inp, weight, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding=conv_type)
    conv_nr = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv)
    conv_dp = tf.nn.dropout(conv_nr, keep_prob= 0.7)
    conv_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_dp)
    return conv_relu

def conv2d(inp, num_filters, filter_size, padding_type, stride=1, acti=tf.nn.relu, bias=True, is_train=True):
    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inp,
                           strides= stride,
                           filters=num_filters,
                           padding = padding_type,
                           kernel_size=[filter_size, filter_size],
                           activation=acti,
                           trainable=is_train,
                           use_bias=bias)
    bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=is_train)
    dp = tf.layers.dropout(bn, rate=0.2, training=is_train)
    return dp    

def max_pool(inp, pfilter_size, pstride, pconv_type):
    max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(inp, ksize=[1, pfilter_size, pfilter_size, 1], strides=[1, pstride, pstride, 1], padding=pconv_type)
    return max_pool

def avg_pool(inp, filter_size, stride, conv_type):
    avg_pool = tf.nn.avg_pool(inp, ksize=[1, filter_size, filter_size, 1], stride=[1, pstride, pstride, 1], padding=conv_type)
    return avg_pool

def avg_pool2d(inp, filter_size, stride, conv_type):
    avg_pool = tf.layers.average_pooling2d(inp, pool_size=[filter_size, filter_size], strides=stride, padding=conv_type)
    return avg_pool

def max_pool2d(inp, filter_size, stride, conv_type):
    max_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inp, pool_size=[filter_size, filter_size], strides=stride, padding=conv_type)
    return max_pool

def import_image_resize(name, size):
    img = Image.open(name)
    img = img.resize((size,size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = np.asarray(img)
    return img
```

#### main.py

```
from conv_utils import *

def import_data():

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

        vgg_raw_file, vgg_labels = label_import_oh('Dog breed dataset//labels.csv')
        data = []
        for i in range(len(vgg_raw_file[:,0])):
            data.append(import_image_resize(path + 'Dog breed dataset//train//' + vgg_raw_file[i,0] +'.jpg', 229))  

        vgg_data = np.asarray(data)

        X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(vgg_data, vgg_labels, test_size= 0.1)
        unique_label = vgg_labels.shape[1]
        X_train = X_train/255
        X_test = X_test/255
        return X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, unique_label

def main():

    fsize = 3
    fstride = 1
    conv_type='SAME'

    pfsize = 2
    pstride = 2
    pconv_type='VALID'

    mini_batch_size = 16

    parameter_server = ["xxxx:yyyy"]
    worker_server = ["xxxx:yyyz", "xxxx:yyyu"]

    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps' : parameter_server, 'worker' : worker_server})

    if job == "ps":
        print('starting ps')
        server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="ps", task_index = task, config=return_config())
        server.join()

    if job == "worker":

        X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, unique_label = import_data()

        is_chief = (task == 0)
        server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index = task, config=return_config())

        worker_device = "/job:%s/task:%d/cpu:0/" % (job, task)

        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster = cluster, worker_device = worker_device)):

            global_step = tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.int32,trainable=False,name='global_step')

            with tf.name_scope('input'):
                X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))
                Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, Y_train.shape[1]))

            with tf.name_scope('model_build'):

                NC = [64, 128, 128, 256, 256, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 4096, 4096, 1000, unique_label]

                conv64 = conv2d(X, NC[0], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                maxpool1 = max_pool2d(conv64, pfsize, pstride, pconv_type)

                conv128 = conv2d(maxpool1, NC[1], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv128a = conv2d(conv128, NC[2], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                maxpool2 = max_pool2d(conv128a, pfsize, pstride, pconv_type)

                conv256a = conv2d(maxpool2, NC[3], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv256b = conv2d(conv256a, NC[4], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv256c = conv2d(conv256b, NC[5], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                maxpool3 = max_pool2d(conv256c, pfsize, pstride, pconv_type)

                conv512a = conv2d(maxpool3, NC[6], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv512b = conv2d(conv512a, NC[7], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv512c = conv2d(conv512b, NC[8], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                maxpool4 = max_pool2d(conv512c, pfsize, pstride, pconv_type)

                conv512d = conv2d(maxpool4, NC[9], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv512e = conv2d(conv512d, NC[10], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                conv512f = conv2d(conv512e, NC[11], fsize, conv_type, stride=1)
                maxpool5 = max_pool2d(conv512f, pfsize, pstride, pconv_type)

                flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(maxpool5)
                fc1 = tf.layers.dense(flatten, units=NC[12], activation=tf.nn.relu)
                fc2 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, units=NC[13], activation=tf.nn.relu)
                fc3 = tf.layers.dense(fc2, units=NC[14], activation=tf.nn.relu)
                Z = tf.layers.dense(fc3, units=NC[15], activation=None)

            with tf.name_scope('cost'):
                cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= Z, labels=Y))

            with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
                predict = tf.argmax(Z, 1)
                correct_predict = tf.equal(predict, tf.argmax(Y, 1))
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))

            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
            optimizer1 = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(optimizer, replicas_to_aggregate=len(worker_server)
                                                        , total_num_replicas=len(worker_server))
            opt = optimizer1.minimize(cost, global_step = global_step)

        init_token_op = optimizer1.get_init_tokens_op()
        chief_queue_runner = optimizer1.get_chief_queue_runner()
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        total_splits = len(worker_server)
        size_of_data = int(X_train.shape[0]/total_splits)
        total_steps = epoch * int( size_of_data / mini_batch_size)


        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
                                is_chief=is_chief,
                                init_op=init_op,
                                global_step = global_step
                                )

        print('Starting training on worker %d'%task)

        print('The size of the data is : ',size_of_data)
        if task == (len(worker_server) - 1):
            X_data = X_train[(task * size_of_data):]
            Y_data = Y_train[(task * size_of_data):]
        else:
            X_data = X_train[(task):(task + 1 ) * size_of_data]
            Y_data = Y_train[(task):(task + 1 ) * size_of_data]

        start=time.time()
        with  sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=return_config()) as sess:

            if is_chief:
                sv.start_queue_runners(sess, [chief_queue_runner])
                sess.run(init_token_op)

            for i in range(epoch):
                #if sv.should_stop() : break
                for X_batch, Y_batch in iterate_minibatches(X_data, Y_data, mini_batch_size, shuffle=True):
                    _, _cost = sess.run([opt, cost], feed_dict={X:X_batch, Y:Y_batch})
                    #print('step : ', gs, ' worker : ', task, 'epoch : ', epoch)

                if i % 5 == 0:
                    _a = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={X:X_test, Y:Y_test})
                    print('The accuracy is : ', _a)

            if is_chief:
                time.sleep(15)


            if not is_chief:
                sv.stop()                                       

        end = time.time() - start
        print('Done , The total time taken is : ', end)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import argparse
    import os

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
    "--job_name",
    type=str,
    default="",
       help="One of 'ps', 'worker'"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
       "--task_index",
        type=int,
        default=0,
        help="Index of task within the job"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
       "--CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES",
        type=int,
        default=0,
        help="The GPUs on which you the code should run"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--learning_rate",
        type=float,
        default=0.001,
        help="the learning rate for the model "
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--epoch",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        help="the learning rate for the model "
    )

    flags, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
    job = flags.job_name
    task = flags.task_index
    CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = flags.CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
    learning_rate = flags.learning_rate
    epoch = flags.epoch

    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="%d" % CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What do you mean by "`I'd like to first have this sorted.`"? Are you asking to have somebody update the code?

Comment: thanks!, excited to be here! i'll like someone to review the code and tell me why the run time is very high.

Comment: Can you share your dataset so we can profile the code?

Comment: Everything beneath `def main()` is improperly indented. What Python version do you target?

Comment: @Mast i used a dog breed dataset from kaggle, you can get it from here https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification/data

Comment: also very sorry about the indentation it got messed up while i copy pasted it here, i have edited it and i am using python 3.5.4

Comment: As what do you save your model? Or your logs? [FileWriter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) is awesome when comparing runs. Load them up afterwards in Tensorboard and compare away.

Comment: I have not been saving my models or logs at all, I'll priorotize it for the first thing in the morning.

Comment: In [revision 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/190823/revisions#rev-arrow-f01bc549-adc0-4fc0-a423-43b301c22a04) I corrected the indentation for that first line of the second file... if everything else should be indented relative to that then you should fix that...

Comment: The rest of the code is not dependant on the indent so that should be fine, thanks

Comment: Do you use the GPU anywhere? I see two unused `gpu1`, `gpu2` variables and some CPU code, but I don't see where the GPUs are directly used. Could be wrong though, I usually use pytorch and not Tensorflow.

Comment: I am creating a cluster and asking TensorFlow to select the best option of either one of the GPU/CPU this happens in the tf.train.replica_device_setter line